# Remove unwanted spikes from varying signal

Tags: python, signals

I have a signal that looks like this (given in blue), and what I want is to remove the unwanted peaks given to yield the signal that I drew by hand to be shown in black. Simple tools like median filter, etc, do not work since the spacing of these peaks can vary widely. Bandpass tools also will distort the edge of the desired black signal, and also the spikes do not appear in any consistent frequency range (i.e., they're not particularly periodic, as can be seen). Does anyone have any other ideas as to how to achieve this?

[image]

Comment: The folks over at the [DSP SE](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/) will probably be more helpful since you're not really asking a programming question.

Comment: Signal processing  question appropriate for https://dsp.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Filtered local minimums?